# Is it possible to force a logitech device to switch to a different reciver? Like logitech flow on win/mac

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, logitech

I'm using multiple Linux Desktop Machines at the same time. Controlling them via those logitech keyboard and mice where you can press a button to switch to a different lt/bt-reciver (e.g. PC).

But it's very annoying if you switch very often back an forth.

**It would be great to force them (e.g. via a shell command or an active Edge) to switch to a different reciver/PC**

**I'm currently using:**

- Logitech MX Anywhere 2s
  (via bluetooth and lt-unified)
  to switch reciver, you have to press a button on the bottom of the mouse
- Logitech K380
  (via Bluetooth)
- Logitech MX Keys (via unified-reciver)

How do you do it?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/marcelhoffs/input-switcher

This is the result of some work(not mine) with Logitech Flow and sniffing what was sent to the mouse/keyboard from Flow to make them switch.  Then just this hidapitester program to send the command yourself.  Took some trial and error, but I got it to work for my MX Keys and Vertical Mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into `Synergy`. It allows controlling multiple computers using only one keyboard/mouse. See https://symless.com/ for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It looks like it would do the trick. But i don't want to stream my keyboard input over the network (maybe the logitech software does it the same way). But just want to force the device via software to switch to a different reciver. But without the annoying button-pressing-on-the-underside.

Comment: @BorstenHorst Data only travels over your local network. To change screens/computers, you just move the mouse pointer over to the other screen.